# how to use overlay fuction with android MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE

Tags: android

I want to use video record function by `Action_Video_Capture`.
The problem is that I don't know how to use overlay function with `Action_Video_Capture`

I don't want an image overlay, I just want a basic line overlay.

**Code**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_choice);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        Button record = (Button) findViewById(R.id.record);
        Button report = (Button) findViewById(R.id.confirm);
        Button probt =(Button) findViewById(R.id.pro);
        record.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent;
                //동영상 촬영버튼
                intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT,5);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add

```
Uri videoUri = Uri.fromFile(mediaFile);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, videoUri);
```